# Return all powers of 2 less then n in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

For a given number n, I need to return all powers of 2 less than n, as a string in a way that elements are separated with "-". If n < 2, it needs to return an empty string.

For example:

n = 20 => 1-2-4-8-16

n = 8 => 1-2-4

I'm a beginner, so any help would be much appreciated! :)

EDIT: this is not working

```
using System; 

class N 
{
   static int[] powerof2(int n) 
   { 
       int[] array = new int[n];
       if (n < 2) 
          return new int[0];
        
       for (int i = 0; i < 8 * sizeof(uint); i++) 
       { 
          int curr = 1 << i; 

          if (curr > n) 
           break; 
  
          array[i] = curr;
    } 
  
    return array; 
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            return (array[i] + "-");
    }
} 

static public void Main () 
{ 
    int n = 10; 
    Console.WriteLine(powerof2(n).ToString()); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what is the question?

Comment: Side note: "If n < 2, it needs to return an empty string." -- *2^0 = 1* is a power of *2* and less than *2*. So you may want to think about that rule again.

Comment: @stickybit it's not my rule, the task is like that

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry, i edited it. this is not working

Comment: `int n2 = 1; var result = new StringBuilder(n2.ToString()); while ((n2 = n2 << 1) < n1) result.Append('-'+n2.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the for loop with the following rule

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
```

Whole solution

```
class Program
    {
        static void powerof2(int n)
        {
            if (n < 2)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
            {
                if (i > 1)
                    Console.Write("-");
                Console.Write(i);   
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            powerof2(20);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [iterator methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) makes this case trivial ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/shE4d4)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetPowersOf2(int maxN)
    {
        for (int p = 1; p < maxN; p *= 2)
        {
            yield return p;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> powersOf2LessThan20 = GetPowersOf2(20);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", powersOf2LessThan20));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go for infinite loop and `TakeWhile` which is more general, but indeed that is fine too...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed, I just didn't want to add Linq to the equation since the OP seems to be a beginner

Comment: obvioulsy OP will not understand `yield` either

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you're looking for:

```
class Program
{
    public static string Pow2LessThan(ulong n)
    {
        if (n < 2)
            return "";

        // start with 2^0
        string res = "1";

        // try further
        int p = 1;
        ulong cnum = 2;

        while (cnum < n)
        {
            res += "-" + cnum.ToString();
            ++p;
            cnum = (ulong)(1 << p);
        }

        return res;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ulong n = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(Pow2LessThan(n));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it's not working is: you never access the class `N` in any way. The call should be

```
Console.WriteLine(N.powerof2(n).ToString());
                  ^^
```

With that modification, you'll be notified that the method `powerof2()` is inaccessible due to its protection level. You need to make it at least internal like so:

```
internal static int[] powerof2(int n)
```

Next, note that you're missing a `}` for that method.

```
    return array; 
}
```

With that fixed, the compiler will tell you that you can't access `array` inside `ToString()`, because the scope of `array` is limited to `powerof2()`. Make the array a field of the class like

```
static  int[] array;
```

Now, the compiler complains about `array.length` in `ToString()`. Fix that by capitalizing `Length`.

Mistake number 6: `ToString()` will return in the first iteration of the loop. It will not return anything if `array.Length` is 0. The function should look a little bit like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        result += array[i] + "-";
    return result;
}
```

Now, this will still not work, because the main method calls `ToString()` on the return value of `powerof2()`, which is of type `int[]` and not of type `N`. That's because your stuff is static. Make it non-static instead and create an instance of `N`.

```
static public void Main () 
{ 
    var n = new N();
    n.powerof2(10); 
    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString()); 
}
```

With 7 issues fixed, the output is now `1-2-4-8-0-0-0-0-0-0-`, so there's still stuff to fix. Maybe you get a little bit of a feeling why everyone proposes a totally different solution.

What else to fix:

- the output of course is still incorrect.
- if someone inputs 4000000000 as the number, you certainly don't want to allocate 4 GB of RAM in the array.
- Why allocate an array at all and not construct the string right away?
- Why `8*sizeof(uint)`? You can't shift more often than `sizeof(uint)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static string powerof2(int n)
    {
          var str = "1" ;
          if (n < 2) 
                return "" ;
          else
          {
              var i = 1;
              while(Math.Pow(2, i)<n)
              {             
                str+="-" +Math.Pow(2, i);
                i++;
              } 
              return str;
          } 
    } 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        powerof2(50);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe, but powerof2(50) outputs 1-2-4-8-16-32-64-128 now. Really, check your answers using LinqPad, before you post them

Comment: It's good that you are very precise but it is not so necessary